# What exercises could help me to gain elasticity?

Tags: exercise, stretching, flexibility, home-exercise

I have never been very flexible and I would like to improve it. I have started training around two weeks ago doing some easy stretching exercises that I was taught at high school.

I've been training with and without resistance bands but I have seen no real progress yet. **What are the best exercises that could help me to gain elasticity?**

For instance, I would like to be able to reach my toes with my fingers which I can't do right now. I'm 21, male, 1.80 m and 72 kg approximately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this site there should be every stretching exercise imaginable. Just do a couple each day, keep at it, be consistent and eventually It'll show:

http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/exercisetype/id/3/exercisetype/stretching